# php something wrong with my query or php

Tags: php, mysql

**Hi please ignore all comments i am trying to insert data in my database but something wrong with my query or my script please help or add some suggestions please because when i click submit button it is not submitting to my database**

```
<?php

    include("connect.php");

    session_start();

    if( !isset($_SESSION['id']))
    {
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }

    //foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
    //{
    //    echo '<p> '.$key.'='.$val.' </p>';
    //}  

    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $queue = $_POST['queue'];
    //$TarosID = $_POST['TarosID'];
    //$Status = $_POST['Status'];
    //$Reason = $_POST['Reason'];

    $date = date("d/m/y");
    $time = time("h:i:s");

    $query = "INSERT INTO sms_traffic_db.table_data name, date, time, queue, TarosID, Status, Reason VALUES '$name, $date, $time, $queue'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result)
    {
        echo "Data Inserted successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error";
    }        
    mysql_close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Not sure about your problem, bus as long as we're here take note that the mysql_* functions are obsolete and deprecated. Also, your code Is highly vulnerable to SQL injection because you are constructing a query string including unescaped variables that come from user input.

Comment: 1° use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql`. Then, add `echo $query` right before `mysqli_query()`, and if nothing is displayed try to display error: add `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of your script

Comment: ** If i add mysqli i get this **   'Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SMS_Traffic\Includes\add_topic.php on line 27
Error'

Answer (score 3):

You need parentheses around your list of columns, and again around your list of values.

If you'd tried `echo mysql_error()` then you would have seen this.

Also...
[image: xkcd]

Comment: **i have added the parentheses still does not work**

Comment: Did you try `mysql_error()`?

Comment: I used '$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());'And got error'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 '

Comment: So that means the close parens right at the end was unexpected. Can you show the full text of the query as it is now?

Answer (score 1):

please check your values field it has only 5 values.

Remaining feild should be null.

if you have to check actual error check

```
   $result = mysql_query($query) or mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 0):

1.correct your insert syntax.check mysql documentation.

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
[INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
{VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
[ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col_name=expr
    [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

2.dont use mysql_query they are deprecated.use mysqli_query.

3.your code is vulnaerable to sql injection.search for relevant topic in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Your code here:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO sms_traffic_db.table_data name, date, time, queue, TarosID, Status, Reason VALUES '$name, $date, $time, $queue'";
```

lists seven columns to insert into, but only four values. MySQL is probably throwing an error as the count of these must match.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a connection to your database `mysql_connect` I think. And put a try catch each time you do a query Look for the `PDO` class, it's a lot easier and better to use.

EDIT

Sorry, didn't see the include at the top
Try this :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sms_traffic_db.table_data (name, date, time, queue, TarosID, Status, Reason) VALUES (".$name.", ".$date.",". $time.", ."$queue.")";
```

EDIT 2 :

So here is what I'll do :

```
<?php
// in your file connect.php
$databaseName = "sms_traffic_db";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPassword = "root";
try{
$con = new Pdo('mysql:dbname=$databaseName;host=localhost', 'root', '');
}catch(PDOException $e){
   var_dump($e);
}
?>

    <?php
// in your main code
    session_start();

        if( !isset($_SESSION['id']))
        {
            header('Location: ../index.php');
        }

        $name = $_SESSION['name'];
        $queue = $_POST['queue'];

        $date = date("d/m/y");
        $time = time("h:i:s");

      // The try catch will help you to get the error 
      // I saw that in your query you say that you'll insert 7 columns but you're inserting only 4

 //    Look also if you have clauses like NOT NULL in your database

       try{
    // this will return you a statement object
    // using this, it prevents SQL Injection
    $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO table_data (name, date, time, queue, TarosID, Status, Reason) VALUES( :name, :date, :time, :queue)');

             $stmt->execute( array( ':name' => $name, ':date' => $date, ':time' => $time
                         ':queue' => $queue
                     ) );

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            var_dump($e); die;
        }


    ?>
```

Comment: ** I have removed the extra fields i had and still does not work **